# Dave Chappelle and Half Baked

Tags: half-baked

Someone once told me that Dave Chappelle was unhappy the way [Half Baked](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120693/) came out, that he wanted it to have either a different tone or something.  I have looked around, but haven't found any hard evidence to support this claim.  Does anyone know of an interview or article that tells what he would have changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an interview from [inside the actors studio](http://screen.genius.com/Dave-chappelle-inside-the-actors-studio-interview-annotated) Chappelle had this to say (about halfway down the page):

> "Half Baked didn't come out the way I wanted it to come out.
> I was real upset about that, cause it was a real cool script,
> And then I saw it, I was like, "Hey, man, you made a weed movie for kids" and it wasn't for kids, the script, you know?
> It was all these things and so much pressure."

You can watch the full interview here. Question 27. http://www.guavaleaf.com/video/21681/Dave-Chappelle--Inside-The-Actors-Studio#sthash.gfJVbwtl.dpbs